# How do I check which of my NVIDIA GPUs is used for display?

Tags: nvidia, multi-gpu, nvidia-smi

I'm on a system with multiple NVIDIA GPUs. One or more of them may - or may not - be used to drive a physical monitor. In my compute work, I want to avoid using that one (or more).

How can I, programmatically, check which GPUs are used for display?

If there's no robust way of doing that, I'll settle for getting those GPUs which are used by an Xorg process (which is what `nvidia-smi` gives me on the command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use the same process, you can check the [NVML API](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml) functions `nvmlDeviceGetDisplayActive` and `nvmlDeviceGetDisplayMode`.
Specifically,

- `nvmlReturn_t nvmlDeviceGetDisplayMode ( nvmlDevice_t device, nvmlEnableState_t* display )` can be used to detect if a physical display is connected to a device.
- `nvmlReturn_t nvmlDeviceGetDisplayActive ( nvmlDevice_t device, nvmlEnableState_t* isActive )` can be used to check if X server is attached to a device, it can be possible that an X server is running, without an attached physical display.

[Link to documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html#group__nvmlDeviceQueries_1gdbefa576c990565696bc5be5ead7bf0f)

Comment: 1. Why do I need the first function if I have the second? 2. Can you please quote the signature and semantics of the function(s)?

Comment: Added signatures, reorder the functions. The OP talks about a physical display, but the question is more general. I think someone might find `nvmlDeviceGetDisplayActive` useful as well, to check whether X server is running on a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on a terminal

```
nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=index,display_mode,display_active
```

For more information check the [nvidia-smi documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf) and `nvidia-smi --help-query-gpu`

Comment: That's nice to know (i.e. beats grepping for Xorg), but I asked about doing it programmatically, not from the command-line. I don't want to spawn a process just to do that.